# ADO.Net INSERT not inserting data

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

I've got a c#.Net 4.5 console application and I'm trying to insert data from a DataTable to a SQL Server 2008R2 database table. I get no errors, but no data gets inserted. Here's my code:

```
Int32 newID = 0;
DataTable dtMaxUserID = GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect("SELECT MAX(UserID)+1 AS NewID FROM TIUser", false, "TrackitCN");
newID = Convert.ToInt32(dtMaxUserID.Rows[0]["NewID"].ToString());

//Get new users from AllUserData
DataColumn dcRowID = new DataColumn("RowID", typeof(Int32));
//dcRowID.AllowDBNull = false;
dcRowID.AutoIncrement = true;
dcRowID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
dcRowID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
//dcRowID.Unique = true;
//dcRowID.ColumnName = "RowID";
DataTable dtNewUsers = new DataTable();
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add(dcRowID);
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("MaxID");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("UserID");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("FullName");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Title");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Phone");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("EMailAddr");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Fax");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Dept");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Dept_Num");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Location");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("UserDef_1");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("UserDef_2");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Login");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Password");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("PasswordFlags");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("LanguageID");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("NTAuthentication");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("NTAccount");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("SID");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("SelfServiceAccess");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("ImagePath");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("CompFlag");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("Employee_ID");
dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("SessionID");
string strQuery = "SELECT " + newID + " AS MaxID, LName" + ", " + "FName AS FullName, Title, Phone, EMail AS EmailAddr, Fax, Department AS Dept, Office AS Location, [Login] AS Employee_ID FROM [User] WHERE StartDate >= CAST(DATEPART(year,getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(month,getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(day,getdate())-1 AS varchar)";
DataTable dtTemp = GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect(strQuery, false, "AllUserDataCN");
foreach (DataRow row in dtTemp.Rows)
    dtNewUsers.ImportRow(row);

SqlTransaction tran = null;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

        //Insert new users into TIUser
        SqlDataAdapter TIUser_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM TIUser WHERE 1 = 0";
        TIUser_adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection, tran);
        TIUser_adapter.Fill(dtNewUsers);
        dtNewUsers.AcceptChanges();
        TIUser_adapter.Update(dtNewUsers);

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

GeneralClassLibrary is a class library we use here for a number of things; here it just executes a SELECT statement on a database. TIUser is the database table. The DataTable, dtNewUsers contains one row. I've verified that by debugging the code and inspecting the DataTable after the ImportRow is done.

---

After following the reply from user3787557 (THANK YOU!), I'm closer, but I'm getting a concurrency violation. I'm working on a development database, and all I'm doing is inserting a record, so I have no idea why there'd be a concurrency violation. One possibility: I alter the structure of the DataTable dtNewUsers by adding two columns. However, before I do the update, I remove those columns. The InsertCommand is fine; I've checked it in SSMS and it parses. Here's my new code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrackitCN"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlTransaction tran = null;
            connection.Open();
            tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                //Create empty TIUser Data Adapter
                SqlDataAdapter TIUser_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommandBuilder TIUser_builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(TIUser_adapter);
                string queryString = "SELECT * FROM TIUser WHERE 1 = 0";
                TIUser_adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection, tran);
                TIUser_adapter.InsertCommand = TIUser_builder.GetInsertCommand();
                TIUser_adapter.UpdateCommand = TIUser_builder.GetUpdateCommand();

                //Get new users from AllUserData
                DataTable dtNewUsers = new DataTable();
                TIUser_adapter.Fill(dtNewUsers);
                DataColumn dcRowID = new DataColumn("RowID", typeof(Int32));
                dcRowID.AutoIncrement = true;
                dcRowID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
                dcRowID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
                dtNewUsers.Columns.Add(dcRowID);
                dtNewUsers.Columns.Add("MaxID");                                        string strQuery = "SELECT " + newID + " AS MaxID, LName + ', ' + FName AS FullName, Title, Phone, EMail AS EmailAddr, Fax, Department AS Dept, Office AS Location, [Login] AS Employee_ID FROM [User] WHERE StartDate >= CAST(DATEPART(year,getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(month,getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(day,getdate())-1 AS varchar)";
                DataTable dtTemp = GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect(strQuery, false, "AllUserDataCN");
                foreach (DataRow row in dtTemp.Rows)
                    dtNewUsers.ImportRow(row);

                //Make sure new users aren't already in Trackit
                foreach (DataRow row in dtNewUsers.Rows)
                {
                    row["UserID"] = (Convert.ToInt32(row["RowID"]) + Convert.ToInt32(row["MaxID"])).ToString();
                    DataTable dtOverlap = GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect("SELECT * FROM TIUser WHERE Employee_ID = '" + row["Employee_ID"].ToString() + "'", false, "TrackitCN");
                    if (dtOverlap.Rows.Count > 0)
                        dtNewUsers.Rows.Remove(row);
                }    

                //Remove MaxID and RowID Columns
                dtNewUsers.Columns.Remove("MaxID");
                dtNewUsers.Columns.Remove("RowID")

                TIUser_adapter.Update(dtNewUsers);
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                GeneralClassLibrary.GeneralEmail.ExceptionNotification(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                tran.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

The Stack Trace I get is:

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)


at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)



at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)



at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)



at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)



at UpdateTrackitUsers.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\06717\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\UpdateTrackitUsersConsole\UpdateTrackitUsersConsole\Program.cs:line 91
```

Line 87 is the line:

```
TIUser_adapter.Update(dtNewUsers);
```

Comment: Can you please include the code that populates the data table

Comment: where is your insert command in the code above?

Comment: It's an update command. I'm using http://visualcsharptutorials.com/ado-net/inserting-records-disconnected-approach and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623446/inserting-just-a-new-record-using-dataset-net-c-sharp-ado-net as references

Comment: side note: in your `catch` block, you'll want to do `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`. Don't lose your precious stacktrace :)

Comment: sstan - thanks! I actually removed a line where I email myself ex.Message and ex.StackTrace, just to simplify things. But the code never goes there, so I have to believe I'm just doing the INSERT wrong.

Comment: If you were going to email something, it should be `ex.ToString()`. That will include all inner exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me. Basically what you're missing on your code is to use SqlCommandBuilder to create InsertCommand and UpdateCommand. Also GET RID of AcceptChanges(). That is going to cause the new row to NOT be sent to the database. One last thing: make sure you mark the MDF database file (if you're using one) properties with "Do Not Copy" otherwise the database gets overridden every time you compile and you can't see your changes.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
    adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["RegionID"] = 5;
    row["RegionDescription"] = "Some region";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    //dt.AcceptChanges();

    int counter = adapter.Update(dt); 
}
```

Comment: FYI I used Northwind DB and Region table to make it simple to work with it.

Comment: OK, I'm getting closer. THANK YOU for all your help. I'm now getting a concurrency violation on the Update statement. I've posted my new code in the question.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception you get.

Comment: The stack trace is too long to put in a comment, so I've added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Right before calling Update(), please check the following properties for any row you have either inserted and or modified: HasError, RowError and RowState. Also post the full stack trace including the inner exceptions. Use the exception ToString() method to get it easily and post it formatted as code, not plain text.

Comment: I've tried to format the stack trace to make it more readable. There is no inner exception; it's null. The only thing I do to the database prior to this code is a SELECT from the same table: SELECT MAX(UserID)+1 AS NewID FROM TIUser. I then take the NewID column from the result and assign it to a variable.

Comment: You don't need to format it by hand, just post it as "CODE" and it will do the formatting for you... Did you inspect HasError, RowError and RowState for each row in your data table?

Comment: There's only one row in the data table. For that row, HasError is false, RowError is an empty string, and RowState's value is Modified. I've reformatted the stack trace as CODE.

Comment: What i would do is to eliminate all the column manipulations, etc, in your code and start with the most basic possible code, like simply inserting one row, and nothing else, and then, once you can get a simple INSERT operation done, start working backwards from there putting back the rest of your code bit by bit until you can identify what exactly is upsetting the Update() method.... troubleshooting 101.... Also, for testing purposes, i would start with a fresh project and re-start your SQL server if possible.

Comment: Will do. Thanks very much for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Let us know what the problem is once you find it.

Comment: Will do - if I ever figure it out.

Comment: I got it. The problem seems to be with the code that adds rows to dtNewUser with an ImportRow. If instead I create a NewRow on dtNewUser and assign each column's value individually, then Add the new row (as you do in your example), it works fine. I don't know why this is, but I'm going to mark your answer as The Answer and upvote it. THANK YOU!!