# Why is the inserted value only visible while the program is running?

Tags: c#, sql

my problem is currently that I add a player to the database and that player is visible only as long as the program runs.

The test() method should add a player to the database.

```
private static void Test()
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Footbal.Properties.Settings.cn"].ConnectionString;

    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO Players(id, player_name, player_price, player_rating) VALUES(@id, @player_name, @player_price, @player_rating)";
    string name = "Ronaldo";

    SqlCommand testInsert = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    testInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 43);
    testInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_name", name);
    testInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_price", 34);
    testInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_rating", 54);

    testInsert.ExecuteScalar();

    connection.Close();
}
```

After this method the DataGridView is filled. (playersTableAdapter acts as a bridge between DataSet(db_PlayersDataSet.Players) and database)

```
playersTableAdapter.Fill(db_PlayersDataSet.Players);
```

[image: DataGridView]

So far everything works as expected. And now when I close the program, the added data is gone.

[image: Database]

What is the problem?

Comment: Show us the _exact_ connection string. 95% chance your database is being overwritten on every build / deploy.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945800/ado-net-insert-not-inserting-data

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\db_Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True" @mjwills

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're using an attached-when-the-program-runs database, meaning that when the project is run a new database (copied from the project folder) is output and attached

Attach your db permanently and adjust your connstr, or just accept the behavior; it'll be fine when the app is deployed

Comment: This is my connstr now: `string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\db_Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

In your test() method, you need to use ExecuteNonQuery() instead of ExecuteScalar(). Just change below line in above code and it should work.

Change

```
testInsert.ExecuteScalar();
```

to

```
testInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Is "Id" Primary Key in the database?
Did you try to insert without "Id", or to use different "Id" for new player?